# What is the acceleration of expansion?

Tags: astrophysics, acceleration, dark-energy, supernova

[image]If me and my pet duck, who weighs next to nothing, were placed far away from any gravity source and in such a way that our mutual attraction was negligible, would I see my duck accelerate away from me?  If so, how fast?

Comment: You should see the duck accelerate away, yes. Exactly how fast depends on the strength of dark energy. My guess (have not seen it explicitly calculated) is that it should be pretty slow: hence for practical purposes the Hubble parameter is a constant.

Comment: It is as a old Q of mine. If I am tethered to a far away galaxy I will (after long time) fly. So expansion make works on me. Where the energy comes from ? If dark energy stay constant is energy conserved at a cosmological scale ? Even the cosmology  books I went through seemed elusive on this point, at least to me